# Remove array values from a key to the end

Tags: php, arrays, loops, filtering

I have the array:

```
$array=array('red'=>12,'blue'=>14,'violet'=>88,'green'=>58);
```

Now I want to remove all values of the array starting from the key 'violet'. So I can get an array equivalent to:

```
$array=array('red'=>12,'blue'=>14);
```

How can I achieve this goal, without looping all the array?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$array=array('red'=>12,'blue'=>14,'violet'=>88,'green'=>58);

$new_array = array_slice($array,0,array_search("violet",array_keys($array)));

print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
array_slice($array,0,array_search("violet",array_keys($array)));
```